# Why does Kylo Ren even fight with Finn in the forest?

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren, telekinesis

After seeing what he can do with Poe(freezing him momentarily) and the blaster shot, couldn't he have just stopped Finn with telekinesis and taken Luke's lightsaber with his own hand?

Why even bother engaging him?

Comment: You could ask this question for every single situation that a competent Force user confronts someone who is not even Force sensitive. If you include *The Clone Wars* and *Rebels* animated series, there are **a lot** of examples where a Jedi/Sith should just use telekinesis on their opponent (or they have successfully used telekinesis to disable their opponent, yet do not follow up), but they decide not to for who knows what reasons. I don't really get it.

Comment: @Ellesedil Obviously, you only earn half XP if you defeat a foe with TK.

Comment: @Yakk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT6Sd0qfR-Y&t=2m43s - I'm sure if Kanan or Ezra had bothered to pick up the discarded lightsaber and just threw up there, they would have gotten more XP than running away. Oh, and saved themselves a season worth of trouble. He's disabled. FINISH HIM!!!

Comment: "Why does Kylo Ren even fight with Finn in the forest?" Well, why did you?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I was not myself at the time! LOL

Comment: @Ellesedil, I could sort of understand a Jedi not following up, as they are supposed to be on the side reason, but with a Sith anything goes. I would expect they would use what ever means to the end they could.

Comment: Because the midichlorians said to.  (This is only half facetious.  Many "why did Force sensitive person X not do obvious thing Y" can be (Force) waved away with "the Force indicated that that would have Bad Thing(tm) consequences".  Alternatively, just because one is Force sensitive does not make one magically make correct choices all the time.)  It's their fault.

Comment: @EricTowers, I can understand that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ren had two motives for fighting with Finn;

- He considers Finn a traitor and wants to *punish him* for betraying the First Order.
- Finn challenged him to a duel. Ren is clearly enough of a ham that he can't resist.

> Finn blocked him again and again, once letting the other man’s beam
> slide against his own and harmlessly off to one side. He
> counterattacked, to no avail. The longer the contest continued, the
> stronger Ren seemed to become. It was as if he was enjoying the
> challenge. Feeding upon it.
>
> At least, it appeared so until Finn parried, swung, and unexpectedly
> stabbed, the tip of his lightsaber beam grazing Ren’s arm. **That made
> it more than a challenge. Taking a step back, Ren reconsidered his
> opponent.** When he closed the distance between them anew, it was with a
> purpose that had been previously lacking. **Expecting an execution, he
> had found a contest. Now he had been touched. It was time for play to
> end.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Laughed out loud on your second bullet point. Can't argue with that. But , still he could have frozen him and slowly pushed the saber into his flesh that way too.

Comment: @KyloRen - That brings us to point 2, Finn challenged him.

Comment: Do they regularly say 'beam' and not 'blade' these days?

Comment: @ThruGog - In the novelisation, they say *beam* far more often than *blade*. 11 instances versus 2

Comment: @Richard - Huh. Interesting! I don't think I've ever seen it called a beam before in that sort of general use. Is that peculiar to the novelisation or is it now the trendy thing? I've not yet read any Disney-canon books.

Comment: @ThruGog - It seems to be common to the Disney novelisations; Rey's Story and the Junior Novelisation also use the word beam more often

Comment: The real question is how Finn was able to survive the fight at all?

Comment: @illage4 - He barely did

Comment: @illage4, exactly!